# SVG synchronization of two animations involving scale and translate simultaneously

Tags: animation, svg, synchronization, scale, translate

I am unable to synchronize a SVG transformation which involves scaling as well as translate. The vertex of a triangle translates from point (967, 491) to (900, 100), simultaneously a png image should also translate with the vertex, but should also scale down or up, as it moves.

To get the original position of the png image, I have correctly used the formula -centerX*(scale factor - 1), -centerY*(scaleFactor - 1). This is the original position before animation. But as the motion starts, I am unable to calculate it final position.

Could anyone help me with this problem.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 800">
 <defs>
  <g id="triangle">
   <desc>Triangle</desc>
   <polygon id="triangle_" points="967,491 738,449 724,603">
    <animate attributeName="points" attributeType="XML"
    begin="0s" dur="5s" from="967,491 738,449 724,603" to="900,100 738,449 724,603" fill="freeze" />
   </polygon>
   <g transform="translate(483,245)">
    <image xlink:href="http://www.alegralabs.com/human.png" x="940" y="442" width="53" height="98" transform="scale(0.5)" style="fill:#FFF">
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" attributeType="XML"
     begin="0s" dur="5s" from="0.5" to="0.2" fill="freeze" />
    </image>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" attributeType="XML"
     begin="0s" dur="5s" to="773,80" fill="freeze" />
     <!--<animateMotion from="0,0" to="241,122" dur="5s" fill="freeze" /> -->
   </g>
   <g>
    <text x="940" y="442">1234</text>
    <animateMotion from="0,0" to="-67,-391" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   <g>
  </g>
  
 </defs>
 <use xlink:href="#triangle" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, make your own life easier and give the image a x/y position such that its center is at 0, i. e. `x="-26.5" y="-48"`. Then the `scale` will not cause any change in positioning of the image. Move the `<text>` inside the `<g>` element, too, so the relative position of image and text remains constant.

Think of the coordinate origin of that group as the single point that is moved around, an it can be the same as the moving vertex of the triangle: `transform="translate(967,491)"`.

After that, one animation can scale the image, and the other move the `<g>` element to its animated position. You can use the same coordinates as for the moving vertex.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 800">
 <defs>
  <g id="triangle">
   <desc>Triangle</desc>
   <polygon id="triangle_" points="967,491 738,449 724,603">
    <animate attributeName="points" attributeType="XML"
    begin="0s" dur="5s" from="967,491 738,449 724,603" to="900,100 738,449 724,603" fill="freeze" />
   </polygon>
   <g transform="translate(967,491)">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" attributeType="XML"
     begin="0s" dur="5s" from="967,491" to="900,100" fill="freeze" />
    <image xlink:href="http://www.alegralabs.com/human.png" x="-26.5" y="-48" width="53" height="98" transform="scale(0.5)" style="fill:#FFF">
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" attributeType="XML"
     begin="0s" dur="5s" from="0.5" to="0.2" fill="freeze" />
    </image>
    <text x="-27" y="-49">1234</text>
   <g>
  </g>
  
 </defs>
 <use xlink:href="#triangle" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Just curious to know why you wrote the <animateTransform.../> above the image

Comment: Because I wrote the <animateTransform .../> just after the <image... /> and it did not work as expected. But anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: The position does not make a difference. Animations are always applied to their immediate parent element. It's only a question of readability - this way the animation is just below the attribute it is applied to.

Comment: Thank you Sir, you are great. Extending this, I am creating a small animation. The numbers that you see are incremental i.e., they will be an increasing counter. So, I have used setInterval, in fact I have tried multiple ways, but the SVG screen becomes shaky. Could you guide me in this regard as to what is the problem. I have created a new post for this in SO, if you could look into it - much appreciated  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333150/svg-updating-multiple-text-nodes-dynamically-make-it-shaky

Comment: I think there is a similar problem here, but no solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765481/d3-flickering-text-on-setinterval-when-update-data-from-csv